# Nltk path similarity specification

Tags: nltk

How can I get the similarity of two words without specifying things like 'n', or the '01'
I'm trying to get the behavior from this website http://marimba.d.umn.edu/cgi-bin/similarity/similarity.cgi?version=yes but nltk seems to want the info in a format like this:

```
wordnet.synset('book.n.01')
```

instead of just `wordnet.synset('book')`

thanks.

Comment: How can I make it consider all the senses instead of just 01? (Assuming that's what the 01 means)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
wordnet.synsets('book')
```

This gives you a list of all synsets 'book' appears in.